# is it possible to convert NSString into unichar

Tags: objective-c, unichar

I have a NSString object and want to change it into unichar.

```
int decimal = [[temp substringFromIndex:2] intValue]; // decimal = 12298

NSString *hex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0x%x", decimal]; // hex = 0x300a

NSString *chineseChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", hex];

// This statement log a different Chinese char every time I run this code 
NSLog(@"%@",chineseChar);
```

When I see the log, It gives different character every time when I run my code.
m I missing something...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`%C` format specifier](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265) takes a 16-bit Unicode character (`unichar`) as input, not an `NSString`.  You're passing in an `NSString`, which is getting reinterpreted as an integer character; since the string can be stored at a different address in memory each time you run, you get that address as an integer, which is why you get a different Chinese character every time you run your code.

Just pass in the character as an integer:

```
unichar decimal = 12298;
NSString *charStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", decimal];
// charStr is now a string containing the single character U+300A,
// LEFT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET
```

Answer (score 3):

How about [`-[NSString characterAtIndex:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-characterAtIndex_)?  It wants a character index and returns a `unichar`.